# Grouping inside for-each based on child element values in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a XML as below -

```
<Page14 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
        xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance"
        xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
        xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri">
      <RegionRow>
      <Region>HI</Region>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20000|16 Workers' Compensation|IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-31</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20100|16 Workers' Compensation|IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20100</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-1</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>24000|16 Workers' Compensation||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>24000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-45.13</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>40000|16 Workers' Compensation||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>40000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-65</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>40010|16 Workers' Compensation||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>40010</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-5.34</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50000|16 Workers' Compensation|Change in IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-16</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50100|16 Workers' Compensation|Change in IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50100</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>1</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>51000|16 Workers' Compensation|Change in Commission Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>51000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in Commission Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-1</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>51000|16 Workers' Compensation|Paid Commissions|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>51000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>16 Workers' Compensation</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Paid Commissions</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-0.05</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20000|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence|IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-28</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20100|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence|IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20100</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>135</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>24000|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>24000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>19.17</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>40000|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>40000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>22</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>40010|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>40010</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-21.24</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50000|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence|Change in IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-261</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50100|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence|Change in IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50100</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-135</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>51000|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence|Change in Commission Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>51000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in Commission Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>1</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>51000|17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence|Paid Commissions|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>51000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Paid Commissions</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-3.3</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20000|17.1 Other Liability - Physical Damage, Occurrence|IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Physical Damage, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>1</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50000|17.1 Other Liability - Physical Damage, Occurrence|Change in IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>17.1 Other Liability - Physical Damage, Occurrence</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-1</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20000|24 Surety|IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>24 Surety</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-458</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>20100|24 Surety|IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>20100</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>24 Surety</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-24</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>24000|24 Surety||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>24000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>24 Surety</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>354.28</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>40010|24 Surety||Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>40010</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>24 Surety</LOB>
         <SpendCategory/>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-819</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50000|24 Surety|Change in IBNR Loss Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50000</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>24 Surety</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR Loss Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>-292</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
      <EachUniqueCombo>
         <CurrentGroup>50100|24 Surety|Change in IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves|Pooled</CurrentGroup>
         <LedgerAccount>50100</LedgerAccount>
         <LOB>24 Surety</LOB>
         <SpendCategory>Change in IBNR ALAE D&amp;CC Reserves</SpendCategory>
         <PooledWorktag>Pooled</PooledWorktag>
         <Sum>24</Sum>
      </EachUniqueCombo>
   </RegionRow>
   <RegionRow>
   <Region>AL</Region>
    ----
   </RegionRow>
   
</Page14>
```

For the above XML, I need to write an xslt that runs for each RegionRow element and within each region, I need to group first based on LOB element and then under that I need to do a sum of element 'Sum' based on certain ledger accounts.

I am trying to write the xslt as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Page_14_EMC"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
    xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri" exclude-result-prefixes=" wd xs" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="single_quote">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ampersand">
        <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="Page14">
        <OutputOfNextXSL>
            <xsl:for-each select="RegionRow">
                <RowData>
                    <Region>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Region"/>
                    </Region>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="EachUniqueCombo" group-by="EachUniqueCombo[LOB = '24 Surety']">
                        <CellOneAllied>
                            <!-- ledger account xyz, -->
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="-1 * sum(EachUniqueCombo[LedgerAccount = '40000' or LedgerAccount = '20000']/xs:decimal(Sum))"/>
                            
                        </CellOneAllied>
<CellTwoAllied>
</CellTwoAllied>
---
--
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
<xsl:for-each-group select= EachUniqueCombo group-by=EachUniqueCombo[LOB = '16 Workers' Compensation']">
  <!-- Sum here based on one or multiple ledger accounts-->
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

The group by can be based on 1 LOB or multiple and similarly the ledger account/spend category inside that grouping based on which I need to do a sum can also be single or multiple. I am not able to get any value based on above group-by logic and then also cannot reach the ledger account or spend category inside the group to be able to do a sum.
Can someone please help achieve this?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve, neither from your verbal description nor from code like `xsl:for-each-group select="EachUniqueCombo" group-by="EachUniqueCombo[LOB = '24 Surety']"` as that selects all `EachUniqueCombo` child elements of the context node as the grouping population and tries to group them by a key formed from a `EachUniqueCombo[LOB = '24 Surety']` child element of each item in the population. As your `EachUniqueCombo` elements don't seem nested that doesn't make sense. Perhaps you simply want to select and sum e.g. `sum(EachUniqueCombo[LOB = '24 Surety']/Sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to "group" the same "LedgerAccount"-Tag with the sum von "Sum"-Tag in each "RegionRow"-Tag

Following XSLT-Code will make this:

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
<RegionRow>

  <xsl:for-each select="//RegionRow"> <!-- seach all RegionRow-Tags -->
     <xsl:for-each-group select="./EachUniqueCombo" group-by="LedgerAccount"> <!-- in each RegionRow-Tag group same LedgerAccounts -->
     <xsl:variable name="key" select="current-grouping-key()"/> <!-- save current key in variable "key" to get the right siblings -->
          <EachUniqueCombo>
               <key><xsl:value-of select="$key"/></key>
               <Sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Sum)"/></Sum> <!-- sum of all same LedgerAccounts / get each Sum-Tag, which has a sibling with the current LedgerAccount (key) -->
          </EachUniqueCombo>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each>

</RegionRow>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## XML-Output for our Sample for the first

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RegionRow>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>20000</key>
        <Sum>-516</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>20100</key>
        <Sum>110</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>24000</key>
        <Sum>328.32</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>40000</key>
        <Sum>-43</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>40010</key>
        <Sum>-845.58</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>50000</key>
        <Sum>-570</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>50100</key>
        <Sum>-110</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <key>51000</key>
        <Sum>-3.3499999999999996</Sum>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
</RegionRow>
```

## XSLT incl. Group-by LOB-Substring (first 3 Characters)

```
<RegionRow>
  <xsl:for-each select="//RegionRow">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="./EachUniqueCombo" group-by="substring(LOB,1,3)">
     <xsl:variable name="LOB-key" select="./LOB"/>
          <EachUniqueCombo>
            <LOB>
               <LOB_SubStr_Value><xsl:value-of select="substring($LOB-key,1,3)"/></LOB_SubStr_Value>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//LedgerAccount[../LOB=$LOB-key]">
                    <xsl:variable name="key" select="."/>
                              <key><xsl:value-of select="$key"/></key>
                              <Sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Sum[../LedgerAccount/text()=$key])"/></Sum> <!-- sum of all same LedgerAccounts in LOB_Substr_Value -->
                    </xsl:for-each>
               </LOB>
          </EachUniqueCombo>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:for-each>
</RegionRow>
```

## Output incl. Group-by LOB-Substring (first 3 Characters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RegionRow>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <LOB>
            <LOB_SubStr_Value>16 </LOB_SubStr_Value>
            <key>20000</key>
            <Sum>-31</Sum>
            <key>20100</key>
            <Sum>-1</Sum>
            <key>24000</key>
            <Sum>-45.13</Sum>
            <key>40000</key>
            <Sum>-65</Sum>
            <key>40010</key>
            <Sum>-5.34</Sum>
            <key>50000</key>
            <Sum>-16</Sum>
            <key>50100</key>
            <Sum>1</Sum>
            <key>51000</key>
            <Sum>-1.05</Sum>
            <key>51000</key>
            <Sum>-1.05</Sum>
        </LOB>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <LOB>
            <LOB_SubStr_Value>17.</LOB_SubStr_Value>
            <key>20000</key>
            <Sum>-28</Sum>
            <key>20100</key>
            <Sum>135</Sum>
            <key>24000</key>
            <Sum>19.17</Sum>
            <key>40000</key>
            <Sum>22</Sum>
            <key>40010</key>
            <Sum>-21.24</Sum>
            <key>50000</key>
            <Sum>-261</Sum>
            <key>50100</key>
            <Sum>-135</Sum>
            <key>51000</key>
            <Sum>-2.3</Sum>
            <key>51000</key>
            <Sum>-2.3</Sum>
        </LOB>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
    <EachUniqueCombo>
        <LOB>
            <LOB_SubStr_Value>24 </LOB_SubStr_Value>
            <key>20000</key>
            <Sum>-458</Sum>
            <key>20100</key>
            <Sum>-24</Sum>
            <key>24000</key>
            <Sum>354.28</Sum>
            <key>40010</key>
            <Sum>-819</Sum>
            <key>50000</key>
            <Sum>-292</Sum>
            <key>50100</key>
            <Sum>24</Sum>
        </LOB>
    </EachUniqueCombo>
</RegionRow>
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas Hauser, Thanks for your help. What I want to achieve is as follows - Fow each RegionRow tag, I need to first group by LOB tag, that said the logic is like for certain cases I want to group by 1 LOB like '16 Workers' Compensation' but for some cases I have to group based on multiple LOB values. Once that is done, I want to group by LedgerAccount tag, which again in certain cases is a single value and for some its multiple values and then do a sum of Sum tag under these. I hope I am a bit clear this time.

Comment: An example of multiple LOBs is '17.1 Other Liability - Bodily Injury, Occurrence' and '17.1 Other Liability - Physical Damage, Occurrence' . I need to group all LOBs starting '17.1' and then group on LedgerAccount.

Comment: Now I got  -- good example
→ You could also group by substrings - e.g.:

<xsl:for-each-group select="./EachUniqueCombo" group-by="substring(LOB,1,3)">
...

In this example the "for-each-group" just group by the first 3 characters from the LOB-Values. → This should work for your given example.

Comment: For LedgerAccount tag, I need for example in one LOB group, I need to group ledger accounts - 40000, 40010, 40020. There are 12 such cases. Per LOB group, the first grouping for LedgerAccount is 40000, then 40000, 40010, 40020, then 5200, then 11400, 24000, then 50000, then again 50000 with some spend category logic as well, then 20000, then 50100, then again 50100 but with some other spendcategory, then 20100, then 51000, then 53160, 53170, 53190. It is difficult to put all the logic conditions here since it will be too much.

Comment: Looks the updated output correct for you?

Comment: I am sorry to confuse everyone but I am not very good with xslt and this complex nesting logic. Thanks though!

Comment: Partially, inside the LOB group, can we add where condition on LedgerAccount, so that I can mention which LedgerAccounts I need to group?

Comment: You can use "<xsl:when test="./LOB='2000'"/>...</xsl:when>"

Comment: Try to draw the output and just pusch the desired output as image to our question.
→ That will help alot and the solution will fly to you 

Comment: Inside of the `for-each-group`, I think you should make use of the function `current-group()` wherever you want to compute the sum e.g. `sum(current-group()/Sum)`, instead of recomputing the group by key comparison.

Comment: @MartinHonnen you are right, that is much more efficient 